# Syntax error while creating table from another table

Tags: java, ms-access

My code:

```
    Statement stmt=null;
    String cmdstr = "create table " + tableName + " as (select * from Master_Sheet);";

        try{            
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(cmdstr);

            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally
        {
            try{
                if(stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Output:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)

Please help, i am very new to java coding.

Answer (score 3):

For Access, the syntax for creating a new table based on the data of a query is:

```
SELECT INTO newTable
FROM oldTable;
```

So your code should be rewritten as:

```
String cmdstr = "insert into table " + tableName + " From Master_Sheet;";
```

Make sure that your SQL statement follow the [MS Access syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx) before you use them in your java code.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking Access to create a table using this SQL statement:

```
create table yourTableName as (select * from Master_Sheet);
```

(including the `;` at the end). It's telling you that's not valid syntax for a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200%28v=office.15%29.aspx). This isn't a Java thing, it's an Access thing. See the linked `CREATE TABLE` documentation. (I linked the latest, be sure to find the one for the version of Access you're using.)